# How to create an auto click button

Tags: html, click, queue

I have a list of cases in the queue that I need to grab. As you can imagine, it's a bit repetitive and time consuming. I'm new at programming and haven't figured a way to create a script that auto-click/grab these cases. Can someone help?

Code to:
1) Search and Click "Grab"
 - will take 4 seconds for the page to refresh
2) Click grab again
3) stop after 50 cases are grabbed

This code doesn't work

```
    window.setTimeout("pushSubmit()",3000);
    function pushSubmit() 
    {document.getElementById('Grab').click();
```

Comment: So clicking "Grab" refreshes your page?

Comment: Right. After you click "grab", it will load into your personal queue. This process takes 5 seconds (Very inefficient!). Therefore, I want a script that clicks "grab", waits for 5 seconds (the time that it takes for it to transfer to my own personal queue), and repeats the process up to 50 cases.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your page is not refreshed in the process, you could keep a counter of how many "Grabs" you have done:

```
var counter = 0;
var maxCount = 50;

function pushSubmit() {
    if(counter++ < maxCount) {
        document.getElementById('Grab').click();
        window.setTimeout(pushSubmit,3000);
    }
}

//start the process
pushSubmit();
```

[Here is a jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/9ADsc/2)

**EDIT:**

Or what I would probably prefer, set up the function so it can be used with any number of iterations.

```
function pushSubmit(max, count) {
    count = typeof count !== 'undefined' ? count : 1;
    if(count <= max) {
        document.getElementById('Grab').click();
        window.setTimeout(function() { pushSubmit(max, ++count) },3000);
    }
}

//start the process with the max number of iterations it should perform
pushSubmit(50);
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/9ADsc/3)

Comment: i rant this through note++ and included the <html> and <script> but it resulted in a compilation error :(. Thank you for your help

Comment: Hmm. Works fine for me. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/9ADsc/5) is an example of it clicking a button. What did your error say exactly?